# Can I add sites/default/files in robots.txt?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Customers in my site sometimes upload files in node which are stored in sites/default/files. Ideally I'd want the file to be hidden from the world. I was shocked one day to find Google listing one private file in its search results.

**So can I add this directory in robots.txt?
Will it affect anything else?** At least search engines will not bring those files open to the world!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the uploads directory to robots.txt google will skip it.

This is how you can add stuff to robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder/
Disallow: /folder/file.htm
```

Comment: I'm asking about the sites/default/files directory specifically. Not any other one. What about all the uploaded images related to other nodes which may be using it as storage areas?

Comment: Maybe I don`t understand your question, but if you want to block that directory from being seen by google or any other robots you can use: User-agent: * Disallow: /sites/default/files/

Comment: I know this but beyond this I wanna know what are the side affects of this for a drupal site. One immediate side affect is that all the images/files in this directory will not be listed in normal/image searches.

Comment: that's the only affect of robots.txt. anyone can still access those directories and files, but search engines (who respect robots.txt) will not index those.

Comment: Then why this directory isn't added by default in robots.txt in Drupal installations?

Comment: Usually you`d want all files to be visible by search engines so it will bring you more visitors. But in your case, you have some files that you want to hide from search engines.