# Disallow: /sites/default/files/ not working for my Drupal Website

Tags: drupal-7, seo, robots.txt, google-search

I am currently working on a Drupal 7 website. I added the following to my robots.txt file (under the `# Directories` section)

```
Disallow: /sites/default/files/
```

But when I type "site:www.example.com filetype:pdf" in Google, it is still able to crawl into my `/sites/default/files` folder. Could anyone please help me figure out why are these still being crawled?

The only relevant link I got here was: [Can I add sites/default/files in robots.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829399/can-i-add-sites-default-files-in-robots-txt) which does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Google's cache is valid for about 2 weeks so your settings will be affective after that time period.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
# Directories
Disallow: /themes/sites/default/files/
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have

```
Disallow: /sites/default/files/
```

in your robots.txt, and the record this line is in has a `User-agent` line that matches Google’s bot, then Google is not allowed to **crawl** any URLs whose paths starts with `/sites/default/files/`.

But Google is still allowed to **index** these URLs (but not the content). For example, when Google finds a link to a blocked page, or when Google was allowed to crawl the pages before, then links to these pages may still show up in Google search results.

If Google also indexed the content from your page, something’s wrong.

- It could be because you only recently blocked the URLs in your robots.txt. If that’s the case, you just have to wait some time until Google catches your robots.txt again.
- It could be that Google is not matched by the record where this `Disallow` line is in. Or because of some other problems with your robots.txt (we’d need to see it to answer this).

Comment: The first explanations makes sense. I recently added this to my robots.txt file.
For the second explanation I have added this for all user-agents. You can see my robots.txt file here : 
https://www.familyoffice.com/robots.txt 

Thank you for taking the time and helping me out here.

Comment: @user3570925: Your robots.txt looks fine. So Google should stop crawling these pathes now/soon. However, as explained, it might be the case that your URLs stay after that, but without taking the title/snippet from your pages.